# CSS @media stops working on mobile on textarea focus

Tags: html, css, web

I have a simple web page with a text box and submit button that is styled differently for desktop users and for mobile users. I have two CSS files linked in my html file that specify the different files using

```
... media="screen and (min-width:1024px)" ...
... media="screen and (max-device-width:480px) and (orientation: portrait)" ...
```

It all works correctly until I click on the text box on my phone. The formatting clears entirely, and I am left with a tiny text box and submit button that I now must zoom to see.

Any ideas?

Comment: Link was posted but removed as I found a workaround.

Comment: @naweinberger And what was that workaround? Is this question still open? If not, please post an own answer or close the question.

Comment: I had a solution for this, but unfortunately lost it when my hard drive crashed. I am not attempting to recreate it at this time.

Comment: I created an answer so that I could close the question, as requested. Now it's been downvoted and deleted. Some warning or advice would be nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, you are not using `meta=viewport` tag and then you tap on `textarea` browser call native behavior and zoom to it. Try to add
 `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`
to your `<head>` of html page.